# Solving Linear Congruences.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Question is -:

**Solve the linear congruence $3x  \equiv  4\left(mod\, \, \, \, 7\right)$, and find the smallest positive integer that is a solution of this congruence**

My Approach-:

$3x  \equiv  4\left(mod\, \, \, \, 7\right)$

$\Rightarrow x  \equiv  3^{-1}\, \,4\left(mod\, \, \, \, 7\right)$

$3^{-1}$ means it is the multiplicative inverse of $3\, \,mod\, \,7$

multiplicative inverse of $3\, \,mod\, \,7$

$\Rightarrow 7=3*2+1$

$\Rightarrow 3=1*3+0$

$\Rightarrow 1=1*7+\left(-2\right)3$

thus $-2$  or   $5$ is the inverse.

Thus i am getting

$\Rightarrow x  \equiv  3^{-1}\, \,4\left(mod\, \, \, \, 7\right)$

$\Rightarrow x  \equiv 20\left(mod\, \, \, \, 7\right)$

But in the solution they are multiplying the inverse $5$ to both sides and get equation as-:

$15 \,x \equiv20 \, \left(mod\,\,7\right) $

and then

$x \equiv 15x\,\equiv\,20\,\equiv\,\,6\,\left(mod\,\,7\right)$

The solution is given [here](http://math.mickeylili.com/files/discrete/141120.pdf)

Please help me out ,where i am wrong!

thanks!

Comment: If you write your equation as $3x\equiv -3\pmod{7}$ the solution is clearly $x\equiv -1\equiv 6\pmod{7}$, there is no need to compute any explicit inverse.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio sir, i know this method.i want to solve this question using the above mentioned method!

Comment: I guess your instructor just intended to prevent negative integers. So she chose to multiply the congruence by $5$.

Comment: @EricClapton there is no harm in learning new concepts ! :)

Comment: It looks like you did pretty much the same thing.  You both multiplied by the inverse of 3.  The only thing I didn't see you do was actually find the smallest positive integer congruent to 20.

Comment: @Mike it would be better if you help me out in solving the same !

Comment: @laura You mean like $20=2(7)+6$?  $x\equiv20\pmod7$ means $x=7k+20$ for some integer $k$.  It's a little unclear what you do and do not understand.

Comment: You get the same solution as in your book why do you think you're wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong, when you write $x \equiv 3^{-1} 4$, then you have
also multiplied both sides by the inverse of $3$.  You're just using
different notation.

Answer (score 0):

writing this as a formal fraction we have $$x\equiv \frac{4}{3}\equiv \frac{11}{3}\equiv \frac{18}{3}\equiv 6\mod 7$$